# Alternative to "lead" function in dplyr package?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, iteration

I need to create a column in my data frame where the new column (`next.1`) starts with row i + 1 of the column `current`. I tried this code with `dplyr` that does the job on the dummy data set. However, it's just not working in my original data frame. I tried to detach the `dplyr` package, restarted R etc, but no luck. I was wondering if there was any other way to do the same job without using `dplyr`?

```
month <- c(1:12)
current <- c(20:31)
df <- data.frame(month, current)
df$month <- as.factor(as.character(df$month))

library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(next.1 = lead(current, default = first(current)))
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is going wrong? This code works fine for me

Comment: You can try `data.table::shift()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(
         next.1 = lead(current),
         # in case you do not want the last value to be `NA`:
         next.1 = ifelse(is.na(next.1), current + 1, next.1)
         )
   month current next.1
1      1      20     21
2      2      21     22
3      3      22     23
4      4      23     24
5      5      24     25
6      6      25     26
7      7      26     27
8      8      27     28
9      9      28     29
10    10      29     30
11    11      30     31
12    12      31     32
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options.

Base R

You can make a new column, where you remove the first entry of the `current` column, then subtract 1 from it, then add the first entry as the last (or you can do NA, but just based this on your dplyr output).

```
df$next.1 <- c(df$current[-1], df$current[1])
```

Output

```
   month current next.1
1      1      20     21
2      2      21     22
3      3      22     23
4      4      23     24
5      5      24     25
6      6      25     26
7      7      26     27
8      8      27     28
9      9      28     29
10    10      29     30
11    11      30     31
12    12      31     20
```

`transform` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

data.table::transform(df, next.1 = c(df$current[-1], df$current[1]))
```

`shift` from `data.table` along with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

    df %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(next.1 = data.table::shift(current, -1, df$current[1]))
```

If you don't want the "20" value for the last row, then you can replace `df$current[1]` with `NA` (or any other value) in all 3 options.